# JavaScript redirect based on Radio-Button Value

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, if-statement, radio-button

I am checking the value of a radio button setup to look like a "Star Rating" system and based on the check redirect the user to a specific page.

But the code below always ends up in the else statement. I am wondering if since the radio button is set to display:none; could that affect my code?

JavaScript added to WordPress Plugin:

```
on_sent_ok: "if (document.getElementByName('review_stars').value=='4' || document.getElementByName('review_stars').value=='5'){location = 'http://my_domain/review-submission/'} else { location = 'http://my_domain/review-thank-you/'};"
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<span id="review_stars" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-starrating wpcf7-validates-as-required review_stars starrating" data-cancel="0" data-def="0">
<span id="mf113" class="star-rating-control">
<div id="mf114" class="rating-cancel">
<div id="mf115" class="star-rating rater-0 star-rating-applied star-rating-live" aria-label="" role="text">
<div id="mf116" class="star-rating rater-0 star-rating-applied star-rating-live" aria-label="" role="text">
<div id="mf117" class="star-rating rater-0 star-rating-applied star-rating-live" aria-label="" role="text">
<a id="mfa23" title="3">3</a>
</div>
<div id="mf118" class="star-rating rater-0 star-rating-applied star-rating-live" aria-label="" role="text">
<div id="mf119" class="star-rating rater-0 star-rating-applied star-rating-live" aria-label="" role="text">
</span>
<input class="star-rating-applied" type="radio" value="1" name="review_stars" style="display: none;">
<input class="star-rating-applied" type="radio" value="2" name="review_stars" style="display: none;">
<input class="star-rating-applied" type="radio" value="3" name="review_stars" style="display: none;">
<input class="star-rating-applied" type="radio" value="4" name="review_stars" style="display: none;">
<input class="star-rating-applied" type="radio" value="5" name="review_stars" style="display: none;">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (notice the plural "elements")

```
document.getElementsByName();
```

This function will return an array of elements that match that name (so you might have to use an index to access the elements).

If you are sure that there is only one of each elements on the page, you can try something like:

```
document.getElementsByName('review_stars')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking at radio buttons, you probably want something like:

```
if (document.getElementsByName('review_stars')[3].checked ||
    document.getElementsByName('review_stars')[4].checked) {    
      location = 'http://my_domain/review-submission/'} 
else { ... }
```